# Why am I getting error LNK1104: cannot open file 'glew32.lib'

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I've already read many answers that wanted to solve this issue but none of them work. I don't think I'm missing anything:

- Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition
- Target = all configurations, all platforms (active = debug, Win32)
- C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories: `H:\#DEV\OpenGL\glew-1.12.0\include`
- Linker > General > Additional Library Directories: `H:\#DEV\OpenGL\glew-1.12.0\lib`
- Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies: `glew32s.lib` (I also
  tried `glew32.lib`)
- Path of both files library files (glew32.lib and glew32s.lib): `H:\#DEV\OpenGL\glew-1.12.0\lib\Release\Win32`.

I have permission to access the file, I didn't specify a dll since I want to use only the static version. I also tried:

```
#define GLEW_STATIC
```

before `#include` and `#pragma comment(linker, "/NODEFAULTLIB:libc.lib")` to no avail.

Comment: Is there a `glew32.lib` in `glew-1.12.0\lib`?

Comment: @axalo no, it's at the address specified above. For some reason stackoverflow doesn't display a backslash.

Comment: Then why don't you add `H:\#DEV\OpenGL\glew-1.12.0\lib\Release\Win32` to the Additional Library Directories instead?

Comment: @axalo I don't know why it was so obvious to me that it looks into subfolders that it didn't even occur to me this. Please make it an answer. In most of the tutorials the `...\lib` address was specified so I hard-coded it in my mind.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Visual Studio doesn't look into the subfolders of the directories you specified in
`Additional Library Directories`.

That means that you have to add the exact path where the library is stored
(which would be in your case `H:\#DEV\OpenGL\glew-1.12.0\lib\Release\Win32`).